# Object versus casted literal object in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I don't really know when to use this :

```
interface IFoo
{
   bar: string;
}

...

let array: IFoo[];

array.push(<IFoo>{ bar: "test" });
```

Or

```
class Foo
{
   bar: string;
}

...

let array: Foo[];
let obj = new Foo();

obj.bar = "test";

array.push(obj);
```

Ths thing is that I'm coming from the C# world and for me, it is cleaner to do the second way, but it's also tempting to use the first way, although it is not as strict as the second option. Therefore, I'm really struggling, for now, I just have the feeling that I can use the one I want, but I'm pretty sure that there are pros and cons for both of them. Unfortunetaly, I couldn't find anything on google.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you casting in the first example? It's unnecessary

Comment: It is indeed but the question remains valid ;-)

Comment: If you just want to have an object with properties then go for the first option with the interface, but if you want to have methods for that object then go with a class

Comment: A rephrasing of @NitzanTomer: Use an interface when you want to describe data. Use a class when you want to provide an implementation (that isn't handled by a service or outside functions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript we actually dont have classes, but only plain objects* ("hash-tables"-y) with prototype functionality. Functions are some kind of object (with a bit syntax sugar on top of it).

*(not academically correctly saying, and hiding some things)

Try the below example inside a browser's debugger, do some inspection

```
var parent = {
   method1: function() { return 1 } ,
   method2: function() { return 2 }
}
var child = Object.create(parent)
child.method2 = function() { return '2a' }

child.__proto__   //shows parent
parent.__proto__  //shows Object (the "root class")
child.method3()   //undefined is not a function
child.method2()   //2a, not 2
child.method1()   //method1 not found, looks at __proto__, returns 1
child.toString    
//looks at child, not found
//looks at child.__proto__ (parent), not found
//looks at child.__proto__.__proto__ (Object), returns function
```

What classes (from ES2015 and transpilers) roughly do is to shim away a bit of the glue code you'd have to write to get the `class` behavior/programming-style from other languages, starting from objects and prototypes.

In ES2015, the class declaration creates a "prototype" object, and `new` (or Object.create**) creates an "instance" object which inherits that propotype.

Now back to typescript...

```
var a : { b : string }
a.b = '4'
```

`{ b : string }` is just an annotation. It goes into the realm of types. Let's say in typescript we have 2 realms, the realm of concrete variables, which end up into the generated code; and the realm of types, which are solely used for assistance/linting, but won't end up in the real JS. `{ b : string }` can be referenced away using either `interface` or `type` syntax

```
type Ta = { b : string } //or
interface Ta { b : string }
var a : Ta
```

Declaring type annotations (which include interfaces) add zero code into the concrete JS realm.

..on the other hand when you use `class`, typescript creates both

- concrete JS code (namely, the prototype object)
- and also a couple of type realm inhabitants.

TL;DR:

Now to the answer, there's no big problem in any of the 2 ways, but using interfaces (and less classes) leans toward the most common javascript coding style. Some JS schools advocate against the use of classes, since you can mostly achieve the same effect through other patterns.

Comment: Okay, so a valid approach would be to use classes when I need advanced objects that contains methods and plain object when it is not the case ? Thanks for the explanation :-P

Comment: mostly like that. The simpler the better.

Answer (score 0):

I think both examples will fail, because you are not initializing the value of `array`, just declaring a type for it.  You need to initialize it something like this:

```
let array : Array<IFoo> = [];
array.push( {bar: "test" } );
```

The advantage of using a class doesn't become significant until you define some other members it, like methods or calculated properties.  In that case, you would want to use `new Foo(...)`.

Comment: For more detail, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12764247/typescript-interface-vs-class-vs-modules-vs-program-vs-function

Comment: Indeed, i forgot the initialization. It is because I typed there code directly and didn't test it ;-)