# typescript class and namescript hierarchy when do importing

Tags: angular, typescript, hierarchy, naming

I have a question about name conflict but didn't cause any errors and seems to export pre usual to the outside scope. Best way to show is in this simplify code;

**Endpoints.model.ts**

```
namespace Endpoints {
 export class FruitWorld {
  apple: string;
  banana: string;
  seller: string;
  sellerId: string;
  get produceDate() {
   ...
  }
 }
}
export class FruitWorld extended Endpoints.FruitWorld {
 Seller: string;
 SellerId: string;
 get ProduceDate() {
  ...
 }
 constructor(...init: Partial<Endpoints.FruitWorld>[]) {
  super();
  init.map(data => {
   delete data.Apple;
   delete data.Banana;
   Object.assign(this, data);
  }
 }
}
export namespace FruitWorld {
 // Some overwrite function 
 // extended functionalities
}
```

**app.ts**

```
import { FruitWorld } "./Endpoints.model";
```

Here is the confusing part, which one of the `FruitWorld` is being imported here? From what I can tell, it is the class get imported.

I read this [stackover question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12764247/typescript-interface-vs-class-vs-modules-vs-program-vs-function) and [this stackover question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38582352/module-vs-namespace-import-vs-require-typescript), but they are not really touching on what if we have a class and a namespace share same name, and exists in the same file. Which gets export?

Comment: Hmm, good question, best way to find out would be to try different attributes names in each `FruitWorld` class and see the one which is defined I guess ?

Comment: Hi @SebastienServouze I think the class inside the namespace `Endpoints` is not a problem here, because it is encapsulated by the namespace and it can only be used in the local file. My concern is the namespace and class share same name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class export [will be overridden by a namespace](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20class%20Foo%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20namespace%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20bar%3B%0D%0A%7D) if a namespace is non-empty:

```
export class Foo { }

export namespace Foo {
    let bar;
}
```

So it persists in compiler output:

```
var Foo = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Foo() {
    }
    return Foo;
}());
exports.Foo = Foo;
(function (Foo) {
    var bar;
})(Foo = exports.Foo || (exports.Foo = {}));
exports.Foo = Foo;
```

And class export [won't be overridden by a namespace](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20class%20Foo%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20namespace%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20bar%3B%0D%0A%7D) if it's empty:

```
export class Foo { }

export namespace Foo {
    // let bar;
}
```

So it's removed from compiler output:

```
var Foo = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Foo() {
    }
    return Foo;
}());
exports.Foo = Foo;
```